Input voltage clamp but not too hot
The system is relatively simple: there is an SMPS which has an absolute maximum input voltage of 80V that it can see. So I've put a TVS diode SZ1SMA48CAT3G on the input which has an absolute max clamp at 77.4V.
The issue is that the input voltage can potentially be at a maximum of 61V for extended periods of time. Testing the system at this voltage causes an unmanageable temp rise in the TVS.
I've attached the current input setup, it's very basic, but I want to know if there is an elegant way to make sure the PSU never sees above 80V while still operating at 61V with low heating.


What power output is the SMPS expected to produce? Why not move the TVS after D4? What not add more diodes like D4 to reduce the terminal voltage? What is the expected surge level at the input?

Roughly 1 W continuous operation. In my experience I order the input so that overvoltage devices are first so that the reverse diode won't ever see the high voltage. I could do that, however if you go up the Vrwm for this family to ensure that your breakdown minimum is above 61V your max clamping voltage is now at 93.6V so you're adding a lot of diodes. I don't know the surge level.

@pb I'll make an answer based on using an emitter follower voltage limiter...

What power output is the SMPS expected to produce? (taken from comments)

Roughly 1 W continuous operation (taken from comments)

If your load is only 1 watt, an input voltage of 60 ish volts would mean around 20 mA of current feeding into the SMPS and this is easily controlled to (say) circa 55 volts with an emitter-follower voltage limiter: -

Image from this dodgy looking site. I say "dodgy" because my PC detected malware was present but, the image is the important thing because it's correct in what it shows.
So, you choose a low-power Zener diode that is appropriate (around 50 or 60 volts) and the emitter output will be about 0.7 to 0.9 volts lower. It's not a great regulator but, importantly, you can choose a 150 volt rated transistor and pick a TVS diode for the supply input that limits to around 100 volts when a surge arrives.
Talking about surges, you really need to figure out what the TVS could see because, they cannot be relied upon for dealing with anything more than short-duration surges but, if the maximum peak is no more than 100 volts then you can rely on the emitter follower and ditch the TVS idea. If the maximum peak is (say) 150 volts then choose an emitter-follower transistor rated at 200 volts.

This was ultimately the way to go. Let me pick a voltage level with this and design everything protection-wise around it. Thank you

The TVS diode is designed to pass current for only short periods of time. If you expect to see 61 V at the input for long periods of time, the reverse standoff voltage of the TVS diode should be greater than 61 V.
I'm not sure it's what you would call an elegant solution, but we use surge suppressors ICs just downstream of our power connectors to provide over voltage, under voltage, reverse voltage, and current limiting protection. An example of one is the Analog Devices LTC4364, but there are others on the market:

With the right mosfets, the LTC4364 can block up to 100 V continuously, and higher voltages for short periods of time. It can be configured to either shut down the load in the event of a surge, or the gate voltage of the mosfet can be modulated to allow some voltage though to keep the load powered (typically for a short period of time). As an added bonus, you can set the timer capacitor to slowly ramp up the gate voltage. This allows you to control the inrush for large capacitance loads.
The following is an example from the data sheet where the LTC4364 sees a 92 V surge but clamps the voltage to the load to 27 V:

We've used the LTC4364 in military and space applications, and recommend them without hesitation.

I have seen these, I can't argue that it doesn't do it all it's just so expensive.

@pbandjazz I agree, it is expensive. The LTC4364 costs about 13 USD, and I'm guessing the supporting components cost about the same, so 26 USD total. The upside is that it is a fairly bulletproof solution and most of the engineering has been done for you. However, only you can determine if the value it adds in protecting your system is worth the time, money, and board space to implement it.

Fast fuse blows in 10ms, usually longer. This TVS can handle 100W in 10ms. I would say blowing fuse using the TVS is at the edge of its capability. Another words the design will not be much reliable.
If you thinking about clamping (without fuse blowing) also. A 2.5mA at 56.1V causes losses 0.14W on TVS. At 61V it will be much more (knee).
Solution:
You need to use a power transistor with heatsink for such a shunt clamping (too bulky), or better disconnect the power supply with mosfet once the overvoltage appears with some hysteresis (schmitt trigger).
